# Generate passbook signature in Java

Tags: java, signature, passbook

I haven't seen any examples on the internet for this so as far as I know this is the first time someone is trying this in Java which I find hard to believe.

I'm just trying to work with the .pem, .p12 and .cer files I've been given to generate a signature file for my manifest.json. Here is what I have, which gives me an InvalidKeyException version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     03

See the comment in the code below where the error is happening. I've viewed a few examples in another languages of how people are doing this with openssl but there must be a Java equivalent??

```
    File pemFile = new File("AWWdevCert.pem");
    File passCer = new File("pass.cer");
    File passP12 = new File("pass.p12"); 

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(passP12));
    PrivateKey privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks); // ERROR HERE


    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(passCer));
    X509Certificate passCert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in); //don't know what to do with this

    File inputFile = new File("WebContent/WEB-INF/Lowes.raw/manifest.json"); 
    FileInputStream freader = null;
    int sizecontent = ((int) inputFile.length());
    byte[] contentbytes = new byte[sizecontent];
    freader = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    System.out.println("\nContent Bytes: " + freader.read(contentbytes, 0, sizecontent));
    freader.close();

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha1WithRSA");
    signature.initSign(privKey);
    signature.update(contentbytes);

    byte[] signedData = signature.sign();

    //create signature file
    File signatureFile = new File(passDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"signature");
```

Comment: Hi @Justin, I know this is an old post, just wondering if you managed to solve the above problem without  jpasskit and managed in Spring framework? I am after a very same solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @justMe I honestly can't remember because it has been a long time. If anything looking at the jpasskit code should help you a little I hope. I was using Spring at the time but probably a very old version of Spring compared to today.

Comment: Hi @Justin, thanks for the reply appreciate it, already had a look at jpasskit but not what I wanted. Many thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [jpasskit](https://github.com/bitzeche/jpasskit/blob/master/jpasskit/src/main/java/de/brendamour/jpasskit/signing/PKSigningUtil.java) project on github

Comment: Thanks! Guess I should have Googled for something more along the lines of "java passkit".

Comment: I am using it with Spring framework, though jpasskit's standlone server implementation is not very useful for me, the abstraction and encapsulation of Pass object system is very easy to use.

Comment: @JerryTian would you mind sharing some info about integrating jpasskit with Spring? I'm trying to use it with Grails and although stand-alone it creates passes nicely, when called from Grails I get `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError - data`, which leaves me with no clue about what happened :/

Comment: @Krystian Although I am not familiar with Grails, I suggest you open another question on this, like "Srping framework and Grails integration with jpasskit failure", and put your full stackstrace there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate signature by using only native sun.security package. Here is an example in Scala (can be easily rewritten for Java)

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import java.security.{MessageDigest, PrivateKey, Signature}
import java.util.Date

import sun.security.pkcs._
import sun.security.util.DerOutputStream
import sun.security.x509.{AlgorithmId, X500Name}

object PKPassSigner {
  def sign(
    signingCert: X509Certificate,
    privateKey: PrivateKey,
    intermediateCert: X509Certificate,
    dataToSing: Array[Byte]
  ): Array[Byte] = {
    val digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA_oid)

    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgorithmId.getName)
    val attributes = new PKCS9Attributes(Array(
      new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.SIGNING_TIME_OID, new Date()),
      new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.MESSAGE_DIGEST_OID, md.digest(dataToSign)),
      new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.CONTENT_TYPE_OID, ContentInfo.DATA_OID)
    ))

    val signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha1WithRSA")
    signature.initSign(privateKey)
    signature.update(attributes.getDerEncoding)
    val signedData = signature.sign()

    val signerInfo = new SignerInfo(
      X500Name.asX500Name(signingCert.getIssuerX500Principal),
      signingCert.getSerialNumber,
      digestAlgorithmId,
      attributes,
      AlgorithmId.get(privateKey.getAlgorithm),
      signedData,
      null
    )

    val p7 = new PKCS7(
      Array(digestAlgorithmId),
      new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DATA_OID, null),
      Array(signingCert, intermediateCert),
      Array(signerInfo)
    )

    val out = new DerOutputStream()
    p7.encodeSignedData(out)
    out.flush()
    val res = out.toByteArray
    out.close()
    res
  }
}
```